# AWS s3 still rendering old html file despite the bucket being empty

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've got a weird one!

My s3 bucket is set up for static website hosting. It previously contained a single `index.html`. That file has since been deleted, the bucket in now empty. Despite this, the old page is still showing up when I go to the URL.

I have it all set up so that I can use my own URL (via route 53) and it is distributed via cloudfront.

The URL is https://blockchainit.cloud

proof that the bucket is empty!

[image]

Any ideas???

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache ?

Comment: yes, it didn't do anything...

Comment: You might want to check the cache controls on CloudFront as well as on S3 bucket which I assume is the origin. Refer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesDefaultTTL

Comment: Thanks, I need to update CloudFront. I appreciate your response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `https` in your vanity URL indicates that S3 can't be the only service involved, because S3 website hosting does not natively support HTTPS.  A check of the HTTP response headers should reveal `X-Cache: Hit from CloudFront`.  You are seeing this because the page is in the CloudFront cache.

Disable the CloudFront distribution if you want to take the site completely offline, or submit an [Invalidation Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) for `/` to clear the CloudFront cache for the main page or `/*` for all files.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) Do you know if I will have to do this every time I update my s3 bucket?

EDIT: This is for future searchers of this topic...the default amount of time that CloudFront looks for new distributions can be changed. Thanks again.

Comment: I am brand new to CloudFront and was hoping you could answer one other question. If I invalidate the old file, will my vanity site automatically display the updated file the next time someone visits the site?

Comment: Yes, unless their browser is caching it.  Invalidation requests tell CloudFront to discard any cached content matching the supplied path.  Once the invalidation request shows that it is complete, CloudFront will no longer serve any matching content it cached prior to the timestamp of the invalidation.